# Angularjs Light version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, reactjs, dotliquid

I use angular in many projects, specially in ASP.NET MVC, but i dont like angular-

- router (also ui-router, this is not much problem indeed as it's just a plugin) - concept of web-apps kills all ASP.NET features
- services and factories - as all of this can be done inside common controller. (This might sound tricky)
- constants and values - as i dont think this is really needed if you use requirejs or other AMD

What i love in angular is just directives, and when i make big nested directive, i use same controller foreach, so there is no `$scope` interacting (less watchers)

```
.controller('BaseGridCtrl', function(){
   //instead of 
   //$scope.value = 123;

   var ctrl = this;
   //this  is for Table-base-directive
   ctrl.value = 123;
   //this  is for Table-head-directive
   ctrl.value2 = 123;
});
.directive('table-base', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div>{{bgc.value}}</div>',
        controller: 'BaseGridCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'bgc'
    }
});
.directive('table-head', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div>{{bgc.value2}}</div>',
        controller: 'BaseGridCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'bgc'
    }
});
.directive('table-foot', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div>{{bgc.value3}}</div>',
        controllerAs: 'bgc',
        controller: function(){
           var ctrl = this;
           ctrl.value3 = 123;
        }
    }
});
```

So the link function is used veeery rare. And specially i like that angular easily detects directive - which is great as you just write 1 tag `<grid>` instead of reactjs components (This also might sound tricky). In my projects i use [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) for razor views (it's stored in database as string) Sample:

```
<grid theme="some" route="localhost:9000/some/action"></grid>
```

So dotLiquid just renders this string w/o problem, or even applies other bingings beside angularjs. And this is great as all stuff is self contained. Which cannot be achieved by reactjs - you need to bootstrap components by yourself

```
React.renderComponent(<Grid />, document.querySelector('#someId'))
```

#### resume

Currently it's heavy, about 100kb, but without all this unnecessary stuff it would be really light. I would like to use only `directive` and `controller` services, Also with server-side rendering angular gonna bootstrap itself on each request which is not wise, but with lighter version it's a bit tradeoff. 
Has anybody tried to strip angular services succesfully? Or is there any consideration, any ideas?

#### edit

[Angular-light](http://angularlight.org/) looks promising, but:

- it doesn't provide HTML tag detection, only attributes
- really ugly, `alight.directives.al.getValue` this looks so bad only for me or someone else?

#### edit2

Ok, that 100kb might not play alot. But consider it as workout, as you might know, angular start only once, at page load, so it must build the app, pull all modules, configure each, then all services of module, then inject them where they are needed, then supply callbacks from factories and services to any who injects them, at least it gonna check if any exists (on each module), all of this happens at start, only once! By wiping up size, we also can minimize javascript execution(indeed it will), factory and service watchers, so we won't need any parts that aren't used. We can even get rid of controllers (and use them inline), only 1 service. `angular.directive` (which is best part of party). Have looked at mustache, handlebars, but they are just like reactjs.

Comment: "as all of this can be done inside common controller" - it's called "spaghetti code".

Comment: Nope. With AMD module loaders, you can separate logic into multiple files, and require then inside controller - separation of concerns.

Comment: Router is in `ngRoute` module, which is a separate file. And ignoring any factories/services that Angular uses internally, without them you couldn't have `$http`, `$parse`, `$compile`(!) or `$window`

Comment: and your AMD modules will be just Angular Services, lol, because Angular services are nothing more than JS objects.

Comment: @MichalCharemza Indeed `$http, $parse, $compile(!) or $window` are providers (except last one, its stupid wrapper)

Comment: @OZ_ you got it, so why would you pay 5-10kb (let's say) for something you can do yourself (and make it even smaller). and now consider there is also factory, constant, value, even config. What if all this stuff could be plugged just like `ngRoute`? Sound good? So you will end up simple angular engine. which maybe will weight 10-50kb. who knows

Comment: Is saving 100KB really worth it? The file should be cached and maybe served by a CDN. Have you found this to be an important bottleneck in your app that makes having a customized version worthy of discussion and long term maintenance?

Comment: so you are trying to invent wheel just because of hypothetical 5kb to save? ridiculous

Comment: we have many directives, over 50 at the time, all of them are self contained, we don't use jquery or other libraries, only angular's `directive` and `controller` services, only. And all this tiny stuff weights over 500kb (with angular). So why would you use truck to deliver 50 pencils?

Comment: don't lie, Angular minified is ~100kb only, and jQuery is not required.

Comment: 50pcs(386kb) + angular(122kb) = 508kb

Comment: I don't know what is "50pcs", it's not related to Angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [Angular Light](http://angularlight.org/) ~15kb (gzipped), it doesn't have services, factories, constants, values, DI, router and so on.

In addition, it has helpful features like text-directives and a support of Object.observe ([benchmark](http://jsperf.com/angularjs-digest/62))

**edit**

It provides HTML tag detection, attributes and comments.

Comment: Does it provide full coverage of angular directive and controller services??

Comment: No, but [there](http://angularlight.org/doc/directives/) are all main directives.

Comment: @evc It provides HTML tag detection, attributes and comments.

Comment: @evc "really ugly, alight.directives.al.getValue ..." - it lets you append, remove, rename, clone directives easily.

Comment: "It provides HTML tag detection, attributes and comments" - can you please share sample if any

Comment: Cool, thanks, please look at https://github.com/lega911/angular-light/issues/12 Gonna mark as answer as soon as issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is meant for full SPA development. This means that you are **not** making full round trips to the server all the time. If your application needs to pass data back and forth, utilize the WEB API controllers and pass JSON up to them.

An Asset Management System I am currently working on is full SPA with WEB API and MVC fully wrapped into its needs. User log-in is processed across a full page request everything else is SPA. Additionally, here is something to read more about using [MVC/WebAPI and Angular](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) together.

If you are trying to use AngularJS instead of something like [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) then you should be using [AngularJS Light](http://angularlight.org/) which was started for this exact purpose. I haven't used this library specifically, but as it is suppose to be an alternative to libraries I do use. The suggestion, if you want Angular and not [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) or [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) use [AngularJS Light](http://angularlight.org/)

Comment: Idea is that we i don't want SPA, but i want some directives that could easily work inside Razor, and yes with web-api. Awesomeness of angular.directives  is that it detects itself, applies bindings, templating system, clever attributes (@,=,& bindings). I want that but don't want whole angular

Comment: AngularJS Light has basic directive support. Though if your just looking for repeated template use you might be better off using a templating library instead. It comes down to what you actually are trying to accomplish and what that really needs to support the feature. By the sound of it, you might be able to get away with some basic KO for templating support or you could use handlebarsJS. It has a feature called helper expressions which are very similar to AngularJSs directive feature. I really haven't used it so I can't speak for how well it does 2way binding which you might be looking for.